# printing values of keys in NSDictionary

Tags: iphone

What I am having so far right now is

> NSArray  *keys     =   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"firstName",@"lastName",@"phoneNumber",@"email",@"password",nil];
>
> NSArray  *objects   =   [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nil",@"nil",@"nil",@"nil",@"abc",nil];
>
> dictionary          =   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objects forKey:keys];
>
> NSLog(@"pass is %@",[keys objectAtIndex:4]);
>
> NSLog(@"value of pass is%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"password"]);

However, What I got from the debugger is

> pass is password
>
> value of pass is (null)

Can anyone explain why the value is null.It should be abc,shouldn't it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line would have given a warning:

`dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:objects forKey:keys];`

It should read:

`NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line you are missing `s`

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in the fallowing  way  also...

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"nil",@"firstName",@"nil",@"lastName",@"nil",@"phoneNumber",@"nil",@"email",@"abc",@"password", nil];
NSLog(@"value of pass is%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"password"]);
```